# Indian citizen, dropped out from college on student visa in Canada

Tags: visas, canada, indian-citizens

So I dropped out from my grad school while in Canada, I'm an Indian citizen. My passport has student visa and Temporary Resident Visa of Canada.

1. I flew out of Canada and haven't entered back in India -- does this matter? Entering India again? (It's been about 5 months since I dropped)
2. I travelled to France, UAE and now I'll be flying back from UAE to Canada, and I hope on my tourist visa -- is that possible?

Just clarifying - my TRV is a completely separate Temporary Resident Visa on my passport I applied for *before* getting my student visa. I then got my student visa and entered canada as a student in November 2021. I'm okay with giving up/not using my Student visa at all. I only plan to stay for 3 weeks in Canada to visit my extended family there.

EDIT:

some important points:

1. TRV issue date: March 2018, Valid upto: November 2026
2. Student Visa issue date: September 2021, Valid upto: September 2023
3. Entered Canada for the first time, using my Student Visa: November 2021
4. Dropped from studies: April 2022
5. Exited Canada (for France): June 2022
6. Haven't been back to India (home country) yet
7. Currently in UAE
8. Planning to travel to Canada (from UAE): September 2022 -- on my TRV

Answer (score 0):

> I flew out of Canada and haven't entered back in India -- does this matter? Entering India again? (It's been about 5 months since I dropped)

It matters. It shows that you have no real ties to India and no intentions of returning there.

> I travelled to France, UAE and now I'll be flying back from UAE to Canada, and I hope on my tourist visa -- is that possible?

To be permitted to enter any country as a visitor you have to show that you don't intend to overstay your welcome and go back home. You have shown so far exactly the opposite, and in the same country you're seeking admission to.

The visa in your passport is not a guarantee to enter, even if the visa itself is still valid. It's just an approval to approach. You may apply to enter. But you still need to satisfy conditions of admission, and as said before - the main one is that you can show that the visit is in fact temporary.

I don't believe you can show that.

Comment: > You have shown so far exactly the opposite

I didn't overstay my welcome in Canada? I did exit the country, I just haven't been back to my home country yet

Comment: @Traveller What is the ideal response to this situation here? As you already know I got myself in a bit of structural mess here. Are there any steps I should take now to make sure everything's sorted out?

Comment: @Ang Notify the Canadian authorities that you dropped out. Go back to India for at least as long as you’ve been out. Apply for another TRV to visit, based on your circumstances *as they are now*.

Comment: @Traveller Gotcha. I'll change my travel plans. As far as notifying goes - do you know if I should (or would?) be getting my student permit marked cancelled on my passport?

Comment: I did not mean to migrate this question - it just got migrated when I said it should be asked on Travel. Because it already had been. It has comments and an answer here though, so maybe close this one? Sorry for the confusion